# Why Does The Dialog Shows Even Though It is Called From Non-Ui Thread?

Tags: android

I was having a problem with the activity not saving its stats when calling a dialog from the main thread using a handler, This code crashes the app because the activity is not saving its stats Error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState:

```
public class CheckIfGameEndsTask implements Runnable
    {

        private boolean CheckIfGameEnds() // calls AsyncTask
        {
            // some code here to check if game ends, returns false if it didn't ...

            Handler mainHandler = new Handler(mContext.getMainLooper());
            Runnable r = new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Dialog_GameEnded dialog = new Dialog_GameEnded(); 
                    dialog.show(mContext.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(), Dialog_GameEnded.DIALOG_TAG); 
                }
            };
            mainHandler.post(r);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            CheckIfGameEnds();
        }

    }
```

The above code as I said crashes my app with the error I mentioned, however this doesn't:

```
public class CheckIfGameEndsTask implements Runnable
    {

        private boolean CheckIfGameEnds() // calls AsyncTask
        {
            // some code here to check if game ends, returns false if it didn't ...

            Dialog_GameEnded dialog = new Dialog_GameEnded(); 
            dialog.show(mContext.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(), Dialog_GameEnded.DIALOG_TAG);

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            CheckIfGameEnds();
        }

    }
```

Does that mean my thread isn't working and I'm working in the main thread all along ? Because when I searched I've read that you shouldn't call anything related to replacing the view: ex: showing dialog, replacing a fragment .. etc , in a thread beside the UI thread or else I'll have exceptions or the code won't run. I do not want to publish my app if it's going to cause such problems.

Edit

I'm calling the thread every time some event occurs like this:

```
new Thread(mThreadTask).start();
```

where is " mThreadTask " is an object of the class above.

Comment: where is your *not-ui thread* ?

Comment: @Blackbelt, not sure what you mean, but I edited the question in the end.

Comment: and `mThreadTask` is an instance of `CheckIfGameEndsTask` ?

Comment: @Blackbelt Yes, it is!